# PowerShell run stored procedure in array

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I wrote the following PowerShell script to run a list of SPs. When I run it doesn't give correct result after the first one but when I run them separately all of them work as the first one.

```
$Sps = "test_sp_HasPaidOrder", 
       "test_sp_HasPaidBKMOrder",
       "test_sp_HasPaidCreditCardOrder"

foreach ($sp in $Sps)
{
    $sp_name = $sp
    echo "- - -  $sp_name - - - "
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=server_adres;Database=db_name;Integrated Security=True"   
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sp_name
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $DataSet.Tables
}
```

Result:

```
PS C:\Users\mesut.gunes\Documents\scripts> .\run_sp1.ps1
- - -  test_sp_HasPaidOrder - - -
1

HasPaidOrder
------------
True
- - -  test_sp_HasPaidBKMOrder - - -
1

- - -  test_sp_HasPaidCreditCardOrder - - -
1
```

I also tried add `Start-Sleep -s 3` after `$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)` to handle parallel execution but not fix it. How can fix this?

Comment: I don't have SQL environment to test this. But, you can try to use `Workflow { ForEach -Parallel (...) {...} }`. You can refer to this link for more details: [ForEach Parallel](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713711.aspx)

Comment: @SavindraSingh it doesn't need to be parallel, I just want to get the result of PSs.

Comment: IMHO, it look like formatting problem. Try `$DataSet.Tables | Out-Default`.

Comment: @PetSerAl thank for solution. it is really what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is know PowerShell problem when outputting multiple objects with different set of properties: only properties of first object are used to determine column headers for table formatting.

```
PS> $a =
>>>     [PSCustomObject]@{a=1;b=2},
>>>     [PSCustomObject]@{b=2;c=3},
>>>     [PSCustomObject]@{c=3;d=4},
>>>     [PSCustomObject]@{d=4;e=5},
>>>     [PSCustomObject]@{e=5;f=6}
PS> function f {$a;$a}
PS> f

a b
- -
1 2
  2



1 2
  2





PS>
```

So that, when latter objects do not have any property in common with first object, it results in printing empty line.

There are multiple ways to overcome this:

- Explicitly specify columns you want to print:

  ```
  PS> f | ft a,b,c,d,e,f

  a b c d e f
  - - - - - -
  1 2
    2 3
      3 4
        4 5
          5 6
  1 2
    2 3
      3 4
        4 5
          5 6


  PS>
  ```
- Use list formatting:

  ```
  PS> f | fl


  a : 1
  b : 2

  b : 2
  c : 3

  c : 3
  d : 4

  d : 4
  e : 5

  e : 5
  f : 6

  a : 1
  b : 2

  b : 2
  c : 3

  c : 3
  d : 4

  d : 4
  e : 5

  e : 5
  f : 6



  PS>
  ```
- Or you can modify function `f` to pipe each individual object to separate instance of `Out-Default` command. Note, that in this case objects a printed on host (or whatever `Out-Default` decide to do) and not become part of function result, so you can not process objects further by pipeline.

  ```
  PS> function f {$a | % {$_ | Out-Default}; $a | % {$_ | Out-Default}}
  PS> f | Out-Null

  a b
  - -
  1 2



  b c
  - -
  2 3



  c d
  - -
  3 4



  d e
  - -
  4 5



  e f
  - -
  5 6



  a b
  - -
  1 2



  b c
  - -
  2 3



  c d
  - -
  3 4



  d e
  - -
  4 5



  e f
  - -
  5 6


  PS>
  ```

  Note, that `Out-Null` does not ignore function output, because function does not really have output it just print something on host.